# pymongo.errors.WriteError: Updating the path 'updates' would create a conflict at 'updates'

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

```
update = {"status":"audited","createdAt":datetime.now(),"createdBy":ObjectId(request.json['userId'])}
result = db.audits.update({"_id": audit["_id"]},{"$set": request.json,"$push":{"updates": update}})
```

how to resolver this conflicts.suggest any solution

Answer (score 0):

It's usually not a good idea to use reserved words like "update" as a variable name;
Just changing the variable named update should reduce the number of errors found;
Also in the future please include the errors returned with a question.